# Assign :value to a array / object member on vue 3 - vuetify input component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js

I'm trying to grab the value of any of inputs like combobox, textfield, switch on this dynamic forms but i'm having no success with it.

**Template:**

```
VDialog(v-model='vDialogTrigger')
  VCard
    VCardTitle
      VIcon mdi-cog
      |  Settings
    VCardText
      VForm
        // ref="settingsComponent"
        VRow(
            v-for='(item, index) in Options' 
            :key='index' 
            align='center'             
          )
          // Context Menu Item starts here
          VCol
            // Name of Setting
            VLabel.pa-2 {{ item.title }}
          VCol.d-flex.flex-column
            // Value of setting
            VTextField.ma-1.pa-1.debug-bg4(
              v-if="item.type === 'TextField'" 
              hide-details
              variant='outlined' 
              v-model='item.value'
            )
            VCombobox.ma-1.pa-1(
              v-if="item.type === 'ComboBox'" 
              hide-details
              variant='outlined' 
              v-model='item.value'
            )
            VSelect.ma-1.pa-1(
              v-if="item.type === 'SelectBox'" 
              hide-details 
              variant='outlined' 
              v-model='item.value'
            )
            VSwitch.align-self-center.ma-1.pa-1(
              v-if="item.type === 'Switch'" 
              hide-details
              variant='outlined' 
              color='primary' 
              v-model='item.value'
            )
            VSlider.align-self-end.ma-1.pa-1(
              v-if="item.type === 'NumberSlider'"
              hide-details
              variant='outlined' 
              v-model='item.value'
            )
            VRangeSlider.align-self-end.ma-1.pa-1(
              v-if="item.type === 'NumberRangeSlider'"
              variant='outlined'
              hide-details
              v-model='item.value'
            )
            component(
              v-if="item.type === 'Custom'" 
              :is='item.component'
              v-bind="VBindProps"
            )
    VCardActions
      VSpacer
      VBtn(@click.stop='CancelForms') Cancel
      VBtn(@click.stop='SendForms') Save
```

**Script (TSX setup):**

```
import type { Component, JSXComponent } from 'vue'
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { useI18n } from 'vue-i18n'

const { t } = useI18n()
const vDialogTrigger = ref(true)

const Options: Array<OptionItem> = [
  {
    title: t('ConfigEnableStatusBar'),
    type: 'Switch',
    value: undefined
  },
  {
    title: t('ConfigEnableTabs'),
    type: 'Switch',
    value: undefined
  },
  {
    title: t('ConfigFontStyle'),
    type: 'ComboBox',
    defaultValue: true,
    subType: 'Standard',
    items: [],
    value: undefined
  }
]

function CancelForms() {
  console.log("Action: Cancel")
  console.log(Options);
  vDialogTrigger.value = false
}

function SendForms() {
  console.log("Action: Send");
  console.log(Options);
  vDialogTrigger.value = false
  
}


/* -- Types Definition -- */
type OptionItem =
  | SwitchOptionItem
  | TextFieldOptionItem
  | NumberSliderOptionItem
  | NumberRangeOptionItem
  | SelectBoxOptionItem
  | ComboBoxOptionItem
  | CustomComponent

interface SwitchOptionItem {
  value: unknown
  title: string
  type: 'Switch'
  defaultValue?: boolean // If undefined, will have his state in "indeterminate"
}
interface TextFieldOptionItem {
  title: string
  value: unknown
  type: 'TextField'
  defaultValue?: string
}
interface NumberSliderOptionItem {
  title: string
  type: 'NumberSlider'
  defaultValue?: number
  value: unknown
  maxValue?: number
  minValue?: number
}
interface NumberRangeOptionItem {
  title: string
  type: 'NumberRangeSlider'
  defaultValue?: number
  value: unknown
  maxValue?: number
  minValue?: number
}
interface ComboBoxOptionItem {
  title: string
  type: 'ComboBox'
  subType: 'Standard' | 'MultiplesTags' | 'Multiples' /* */
  value: unknown
  items: Array<unknown>
  defaultValue: unknown
}
interface SelectBoxOptionItem {
  title: string
  type: 'SelectBox'
  subType: 'Standard' | 'MultiplesTags' | 'Multiples' /* */
  value: unknown
  items: Array<unknown>
  defaultValue: unknown
}
interface CustomComponent {
  value: unknown
  title?: string
  type: 'Custom'
  component: JSXComponent | Component
  // cSpell: words vbindprops
  vbindprops?: any
}
```

I tried ``:value=somearray[index]`` but it doesn't update the variable. With v-model, is kinda broken, it doesn't update in time but when writing or changing the state, it stays stuck on starting value (it means, the console.log would show updated values but on interface, it just locked their state / value.)

Answer (score 1):

Your `Options` array isn't reactive by default. It's just a plain Array. When we call `ref()` or `reactive()` we're wrapping it in a `Proxy` (mostly) to wire-up reactivity. One option for you would be to use the `set()` method and create a new object when you update the value. This has a pitfall, though, of forcing a re-render and re-draw for any members reliant on the values of this object.

Make sure to `import { set } from 'vue'`;

```
const Options = reactive({
  value: Array<OptionItem> = [
    {
      title: t('ConfigEnableStatusBar'),
      type: 'Switch',
      value: undefined
    },
    {
      title: t('ConfigEnableTabs'),
      type: 'Switch',
      value: undefined
    },
    {
      title: t('ConfigFontStyle'),
      type: 'ComboBox',
      defaultValue: true,
      subType: 'Standard',
      items: [],
      value: undefined
    }
  ]
})
```

Then define a method to receive the index and the updated value:

```
const setOptionValue = (index: number, value: string) => {
  set(
    Options.value, // the object we are working on
    index, //index of the value to force reactivity
    Object.assign({}, Options.value[index], { value }) // the new object with the updated value
  )
}
```

Update the signature of your `model` bindings to use `:value` bindings with an `@change` event instead:

```
//...
:value='item.value'
@change='(e) => setOptionValue(index, e.target.value)'
```

Comment: It doesn't work!
The `set()` method doesn't exist in vue 3, only on v2.
I tried to readapt it to work on vue 3, but I've got no success, toggling the switch once or twice might cause some bugs, like it only target the first component and the object "Options" doesn't change.